Smallest value of $k$ for which a function approaches $0$ as $x$ goes to $\infty$
I was playing around with factorials on desmos and trying to find some inequality between $x!$ and $\sqrt[x]{x}!$. After a bit I formulated the following question:
What is the smallest value of $k$ such that $ \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x!}{\left(\sqrt[x]{x}!\right)^{(x^k)}}=0 $?
I know that $2 < k \leq e$, but I don't know what the smallest is. Any help would be appreciated!

Can you show how you arrived at $2<k\le e$?

@GregMartin I was attempting to rigorously prove that $k > 2$, but I wasn't really able to get a good proof for that. I tried to show it by splitting $x$ into groups of $~\sqrt[x]{x}$ consecutive numbers and seeing how many times $\sqrt[x]{x}!$ went into their product and then added up all the resulting values. I originally tested values on desmos and then plugged them into wolfram alpha. From what it outputted $k=2$ resulted in $\infty$ and $k=e$ was $0$, but for anything in-between it said that there was insufficient time to determine the limit and outputted $0$ as the result.

Either Wolframalpha is incorrect or you made a typo. I think that @GregMartin is hinting at the fact that $k$ doesn’t have to be greater than $2$. Try to simplify the expression in the limit.
